# geom_hex (ggplot2) displays an empty plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to make a hexagonal heatmap of some data using `geom_hex`, but the plot displayed is empty, like this : 
[(empty plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3OTD.png)

I'm pretty sure the error doesn't come from my code, since when using similar code to plot a square heatmap, the plot is displayed correctly. Does anyone have a clue where that comes from, or any way to understand what ggplot2 is doing in this situation ?

Here is my code, this is the [source](https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2018-06.csv) of the data.

```
cab <- read.csv("yellow_tripdata_2018-06.csv")
cab <- cab[sample(nrow(cab), 10000), ]
library(ggplot2)
taxic <- ggplot(cab, aes(x=tip_amount, y=fare_amount)) + 
         geom_hex() + 
         xlab("tip amount") + ylab("fare amount") +
         xlim(0,15) + ylim(0,75) +
         ggtitle("hexagonal heatmap of tip amount vs. fare amount")
taxic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a similar display error when trying to replicate. Try installing and calling the 'hexbin' package, should do the trick.

```
install.packages('hexbin')
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)

cab <- read.csv("yellow_tripdata_2018-06.csv")
cab <- cab[sample(nrow(cab), 10000), ]
taxic <- ggplot(cab, aes(x=tip_amount, y=fare_amount)) + 
         geom_hex() + 
         xlab("tip amount") + ylab("fare amount") +
         xlim(0,15) + ylim(0,75) +
         ggtitle("hexagonal heatmap of tip amount vs. fare 
         amount")
taxic
```

Comment: It worked !! Thanks a lot (fyi, I installed the package but didn't need to call library(hexbin) in my code)